# Jinja2 templated file with json safe multiline include

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a problem with a Jinja2 template I'm writing (called from Ansible).

The resultant file is a JSON file that I will send to an API (either with Ansible URI module or with curl).  The template looks like this and basically works:

```
{
  "description" : "my description",
  "pipeline": "{% include 'root/pipeline.j2' %}"
}
```

The problem is that the content of root/pipeline.j2 is quite complex and includes multiple lines, quote characters and any number of other things that make the json file I'm creating invalid.  What I want to do is parse the included file through a filter to convert it to a JSON valid string; something like this:

```
{
  "description" : "my description",
  "pipeline": "{% include 'root/pipeline.j2' | to_json %}"
}
```

But that doesn't work, probably because the filter is acting on the filename, not the included content.

Just for a little clarity when I create the template at the moment I see pipeline gets set to something like this:

```
  "pipeline": "input {
  "input1" {
  <snipped>
  "
```

It should appear thus:

```
  "pipeline": "input {\n      \"input1\" {<snipped>"
```

NB: I'm only giving the first couple of lines and I am using 'snipped' where I have remove the rest of the config.

Can anyone tell me how I can use an include within a jinja2 template that renders the result as a single line valid json string?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find a solution to my own question.  Within the template that provides the JSON that is an API payload I am now setting a variable to the content of the pipeline template, which makes it easy to filter it with to_json:

```
{% set pipeline = lookup('template', 'root/pipeline.j2') %}
{
  "description" : "my description",
  "pipeline": {{ pipeline | to_json }}
}
```

I will leave this quesiton answer open for a while in case anyone can supply a better answer or explain why this is not a good one.

Thanks.